# Calculate previous year based on this year condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

Let's say i have a table called Orders with number of units sold by resellers in Country by date

```
Country ResellerID Date   Units
3       1          May-17 7
3       1          May-16 4
3       2          May-16 3
2       3          May-16 5
2       3          May-17 8
```

I have to compare total units sold in specific month basing on a slicer selection to the last year total units in the corresponding month. This is relatively easy and I do this using the formula below

UnitsLastYear = CALCULATE(SUM(Orders[Units]),SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Orders[Date]))

So for May-17 chosen on the slicer I have:
This year = 15
Last Year = 12

However there is another condition for calculating last year's value and this is that I should only take Resellers that sold anything in current year's selected month so in this example ResellerID = 2 should be excluded from last year calculation and Last Year should have value of 9

Does anyone can help how to transform this calculation so that it would rflect this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying it to the following:

```
= CALCULATE(SUM(Orders[Units]),
            SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Orders[Date]),
            Orders[ResellerID] IN VALUES(Orders[ResellerID]))
```

This will only sum the `[ResellerID]` values that appear in the current filter context. Since there are no `ResellerID = 2` in May-17, those are excluded from the previous year calculation.

Comment: If I could I would add 10 points to useful not one. It looks like it is working however I do not understand why. Well I understand that it is context thing but I don't exactly understand why if you have this part Orders[ResellerID] IN VALUES(Orders[ResellerID]) then first reference is taking full set of values without a context chosen in a slicer and seceond reference to the same table and column takes only values from month chosen in the slicer, why first reference is taking a context of last year as I assum. Could you explain? Thanks

Comment: @nothingman The function `VALUES()` returns all the distinct values in the current filter context. Since you have May-17 chosen, `VALUES(Orders[ResellerID]) = {1, 3}`. So the code `Orders[ResellerID] IN VALUES(Orders[ResellerID])` says the ID must be `1` or `3`. The first reference isn't taking a full set of values, it's simply identifying which column you are filtering.